# How to line up social media feeds?

Tags: html, css

I have a facebook social media feed and a twitter social media feed lined up next to each other, however the twitter feed doesn't reach the bottom of the div, and therefore isn't aligned with the facebook feed. How would I go about fixing this?

The HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">        
        <!-- MAIN CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0&appId=186952699372427&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>

        <div class="block__73694 saddam-main">
            <div class="socialMediaContainer">
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
                <script async="1" defer="1" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0"></script>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 col-md-12 offset-md-0 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
                            <div class="totalrowsadam">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 marsaddam">
                                        <div class="saddam1">
                                            <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Facebook/" data-small-header="" data-adapt-container-width="1" data-hide-cover="" data-show-facepile="" data-show-posts="true" data-width="600"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/Facebook/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Facebook/">Facebook</a></blockquote>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                    <div class="saddam2">
                                        <div id="twitter">
                                            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="100%" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




</body>
```

The CSS:

```
/*Social Media */
.socialMediaContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 50vh;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.fb-page{
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The file also contains the bootstrap.min.css but it is too big to allow me to post.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add a [mcve]. No one is going to visit github to download your zip file

Comment: I've added the HTML and CSS now but cannot add bootstrap.min.css

Comment: You can create a working snippet in your question and link to a Bootstrap CDN